# Run-time error 424. Object required

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code. While running it I am getting the message:

> "Run-time error 424. Object required".

```vba
Sub test()
Dim ws as Worksheet, Sr as Range, c as Range
 Set ws = Activesheet

   With ws
    Set Sr = Range(.Cells(2,2), .Cells(10,2))
    For Each c in Sr
     If c.Value= "a" Then c.Offset(0,1).Value = "b"
    Next
   End with
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to assign `Range` with your `With ws`.

Comment: on which line do you gett the error?

Comment: I am getting no errors with the above (edited) code. My code looks at `B2:B10` and if it finds the letter "a", it places the letter "b" one cell immediately to the right of the found "a". What is your intention with the code? Perhaps you only had it formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Do you have an error value anywhere?

Comment: I agree with @TotsieMae here. Running the code (copy and paste) I receive no error and it runs as I expect it to. What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Judging by the non-VBE formatted code, the posted code is probably not what is actually being used, and the cause of the error has been lost while the code was retyped.  Please copy/paste your **exact** code from the VB editor into the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think K.Davis has the answer

```
sub test()
    Dim ws as Worksheet, Sr as Range, c as Range
    Set ws = Activesheet
    With ws
        Set Sr= .Range(.Cells(2,2), .Cells(10,2)) '***Added . in front of Range( so that range is on the ws
        For Each c in Sr
            If c.Value= "a" then c.Offset(0,1).value= "b"
        Next
    End with
End Sub
```

Comment: Even if the `ActiveSheet` was changed between the `Set ws = ActiveSheet` and the `Set Sr = ...` statement, the `Range` defined as being between two cells on `ws` will correctly refer to the range on `ws`.  (But it is still a good idea to add the extra `.`, just because it is a good habit to have.)